# Ghusl after having a wet dream

Tags: taharah, ghusl

Asalam o alaikum.
I experinced a wet dream due to which Ghusl was necessary. I did Ghusl and poured water over the whole body but the area between my toe fingers remained dry. After 2-3 hrs, I did Wudu in which I poured water over the area which had remained dry formerly.
Is the condition of Ghusl after wet dream met here or not?
Kindly guide